# Find lexicographical order of Reverse Polish Notation (postfix) expression?

Tags: python, postfix-notation

I have written a python program to convert an infix expression to a postfix expression (aka Reverse Polish Notation). In my problem, only digits 0-9 appear, as well as the operators * and +.
I now need to find the lexicographically largest string that represents the postfix equation.
Example:

- Infix eq: 2*4*3+9*3+5
- Postfix eq: 24*3*93*+5+
- Lex. largest: 243**93*5++ <---- I have no idea how to get this

Comment: Define 'lexicographically largest'.

Answer (score -1):

Given those constraints (only digits between 0 and 9, no spaces, only multiplication and summation), the following will do what you want:

```
expr1 = '2*4*3+9*3+5'
expr2 = '9*3+5+3*4*2'

def reverse_polish_nation(expr):
    terms = expr.split('+')
    facs = [ sorted(term.split('*')) for term in terms ]

    rpn_terms = ['{}{}'.format(''.join(factors),
        '*'*(len(factors)-1)) for factors in facs]
    rpn_expr = '{}{}'.format(''.join(sorted(rpn_terms)), '+'*(len(rpn_terms)-1))
    return rpn_expr

print(reverse_polish_nation(expr1), reverse_polish_nation(expr2) )
# output: ('234**39*5++', '234**39*5++')
```